# Angular 5 + RxJS: using observables in the component without subscribing to them

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I normally tend to use Observables in components by passing them into functions through template using `myFunction(myObservable$ | async)` and it works quite well.

However, in my template I have an output function that emits values to the parent component.

```
<my-component
   [myInput]="something$ | async"
   (childOutputEmitter)="onChildEmitFunction($event)">
</my-component>
```

The problem is the `onChildEmitFunction()` function I need combine both the emitted value ($event) and the `myObservable$ | async` values.

This doesn't seem to work though:

```
<my-component
   [myInput]="something$ | async"
   (childOutputEmitter)="onChildEmitFunction($event, (myObservable$ | async))">
</my-component>
```

Is there a way to pass the value of myObservable$ to onChildEmitFunction() without subscribing to it and storing the value in another variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `*ngIf` directive to use the value from the observable multiple times.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="something$ | async as something">
  <my-component
     [myInput]="something"
     (childOutputEmitter)="onChildEmitFunction($event, something)">
  </my-component>
</ng-container>
```

Also note that if `async` pipe is used with HTTP, each pipe could trigger an individual request.